# Cannot set .innerHTML of null even after DOM load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, innerhtml

I keep getting the error "Cannot set .innerHTML of null". I've tried linking the script before the last body tag, as well. I'm using double-quotes consistently, everything is spelled correctly, and the script runs. I noticed the two divs within the weatherBox div still aren't loading. They don't show up in dev tools.

I can inject the temperature value into the weatherBox div, and it shows up. But that's not where I want it.

The HTML:

```
<p>Stuff should load here:</p>
<div id="weatherBox">
    <div id="current"></div>
    <div id="forecast"></div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(myRequest.readyState === 4){
        if(myRequest.status ===200){
        document.getElementById("weatherBox").innerHTML = "load success. see console.";
        var weather = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
        console.log(weather);
        document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = weather.current_observation.feelslike_f;

        } 
    }
};

myRequest.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/ceb5d155ada684a6/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/WI/Oshkosh.json");

myRequest.send();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you set the `innerHTML` on `<div id="weatherBox">`, you are completely replacing the contents.

```
document.getElementById("weatherBox").innerHTML = "load success. see console.";
```

The `<div id="current"></div>` element gets removed from the `<div id="weatherBox">`.

```
<div id="weatherBox">
    <div id="current"></div>
    <div id="forecast"></div>
</div>
```

Then when you try to access this element after erasing it, it fails.

```
document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = weather.current_observation.feelslike_f;
```

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know .innerHTML straight up replaced everything within an element. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You deleted #current by setting the innerHTML of #weatherBox!  Oh boy...

Ack, beaten to the punch.